# windows batch to recursively scan files in 1 level subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have many projects (let's say `D:\Projects\`), each of which has it's own directory. In some of directories (not all) there is bat file (`sonar-runner.bat`). I want to write windows batch script to run this .bat files sequentialy for each subfolders:

```
for /r %%i in (sonar-runner.bat) do (
@call "%%i"
pause
)
pause
```

However using this approach I faced problem where the same files in inner directories are executed (for example `D:\Projects\Main\Inner\sonar-runner.bat`). I don't want this to happen. I only want to look for file through projects folders (let's say subfolders of 1st level). Could anybody tell me how can I achieve that?

**Edit**
I have tried another approach:

```
for /D %%i in (*) do (
for %%j in (%%i\sonar-runner.bat) do (
    @call "%%j"
    pause
    )
)
pause
```

But i'm not sure about performance in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for /d /r "D:\Projects" %%i in (*) do (
    pushd "%%~i"
    echo(%%i|findstr /r "^.:\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*$" >nul&&call sonar-runner.bat
    popd
)
```

Comment: actualy I haven't tried it, but it looks OK, i'm using my own example (after edit)

Comment: I made an edit, added `findstr` to execute the bat only one subfolder level.

Answer (score 1):

This is much more efficient.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b ') do (
pushd "%%a"
if exist "sonar-runner.bat" call "sonar-runner.bat"
popd
)
popd
pause
```