# Windows command line to findstr 1 level of subdirectory down

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

Looking for the command line (or batch) that will do the following,

I have 3 levels of directories and need to search for a specific string contained in text files, searching all files, 1 level subdirectory down.

So I know this will recursively search for the string

findstr /S "STRING" *

But I don't want the search to go father than only 1 subdirectory level down.

Seems like a simple thing but I could not find anything solid. The closest thing I could find was something like this thread..

[windows batch to recursively scan files in 1 level subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793545/windows-batch-to-recursively-scan-files-in-1-level-subfolders)

However, before going batch is there a simpler (command line) way to this rather, apparently simple task?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: And, what is the output you need?

Comment: Output to a text file would be fine.

Comment: And what should the contents of the text file be? The lines containing the strings, the name of the files found, both, another information, ...?

Comment: Oh sorry, Name of the file and the line it was found. The output that findstr normally gives you with out any extra flags is plenty sufficient for me. Thank you for your attention MC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it from the command line and write `file.log` into the current folder

```
for /d %a in (*) do findstr "STRING" "%a\*">>file.log
```

Comment: This works efficiently and perfectly! Many thanks to you and all of you who took the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

#### Child Directory Search Only (No Parents or Grandchildren)

Here is a one line command to enumerate the current working directory children directories `dir /ad/b` and search each directory for files containing the search string.  Results are saved out to a text file.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /ad/b') do @findstr "STRING" "%~A\*" >> results.txt
```

**Note:** That as currently configured, a result line will be output for each matching line in a file.  Meaning that multiple find results may be output for a single file.

#### Example of results.txt

```
ChildFolderA\File1.txt:line with STRING
ChildFolderA\File1.txt:another line with STRING in file1
ChildFolderA\File2.txt:another file and line with STRING
ChildFolderB\File5.txt:another folder with a file containing the search STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
(@for /d %%a in (*) do @for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do @echo(%%~fb)|findstr /f:/ /c:"string" > file.txt
```

This will enumerate all the files one level down and send this list of files to a findstr command. findstr will search the string into the indicated list and send output to final file

To use from command line, replace the double percent signs `%%` with single ones `%`